Crystal Report - Try to show/hide a section if two conditions exist in database or not
I'm still new at Crystal Report and I've got a problem I've been working on for the last 3 days and it's driving me nuts. I need a section of the report to be displayed when a combination of two pieces of information (option dept = 11400 and option# = 1) exists in the database for a specific job, no matter what else is in my tables. The columns can contain other info, but they must not influence the display.
For the record, the table2 must remain connected in Left joint otherwise the rest of the report won't work. And I working in SAP Crystal Report 2016.
This list should explain what I'm looking for :



Job #(Table1)
Option Dept.(table2)
Option #(table2)
Result I need




1
11200
1
Don’t show


2
NULL
NULL
Don’t show


3
11400
1
Show


4
11200
1
Show


4
11400
1
Show


5
11400
2
Don’t show



With the suppress function and the formula below, I'm almost there. However, it doesn't work when I have several "Option Dept." entries for the same job (e.g., Job #4). I’m not sure if this is because the first row with 11200 takes precedence or if it doesn’t read the second row correctly, but any formula I’ve tried results in suppression under these conditions. I've experimented with several approaches, but none have achieved the desired result.

if isnull({Table2.optiondept}) then True

else

(if {Table2.optiondept}="11400" and {Table2.option#}=1 then False else True)

